# dynamic object properties javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, dynamic

Having issues with this code block:

```
var name = "";
var nutrients = {};
var tds = document.getElementById('data').getElementsByTagName('td');

name = tds[0].innerHTML;
nutrients[name].val = tds[1].innerHTML;
alert(nutrients.Energy.val);
```

If I take out the `.val` on both lines, the code works. I'm trying to dynamically create the "
nutrients" abject by extracting information from a table. "Energy", and all 50 of nutrient names must have a "value" and a "unit" property. Eventually this will be a loop.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Check your error console, it tells you what happened.

Comment: `nutrients["name"]` is undefined when you want to assign val.. you can just to `nutrients["name"] = tds[1].innerHTML` and should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to assign

```
nutrients[name].val = tds[1].innerHTML;
```

the `nutrients` object is still empty, and `nutrients["Energy"]` (or whatever) will be undefined; throwing an exception when beeing assigned a property. Instead, use

```
nutrients[name] = {
    val: tds[1].innerHTML
};
```