# ExtJS 5.1.1 Trigger a button 'click' event from another event handler

Tags: extjs5

I'm using ExtJS 5.1.1

I'm trying to trigger a button click event or simply excute the event handler of this button.

View File:

```
    {xtype: 'button',
        itemId: 'searchBtn',
        listeners:{
            click: 'mainSearch'
        }
    }
```

Controller File:

```
specialKeySearch: function(event){
    if (event.getKey() == event.ENTER){
        // Trigger 'mainSearch' event handler or click event of button
    }
}

mainSearch: function(){
    alert("something");
}
```

I tried so many options, but none of them works. so please point out where the issue is. Below are some I have tried:

1.

```
document.getElementById('searchBtn').click();
```

2.

```
 Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#searchBtn')[0].fireEvent('click', Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#searchBtn')[0]);
```

3.

```
parent.child('button[itemId=searchBtn]').fireEvent('click', parent.child('button[itemId=searchBtn]'));
```

Please tell how to trigger a button click event or simply excute the event handler of this button.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic object properties javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118525/dynamic-object-properties-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a JavaScript question than ExtJS. But try `tempResult.data[tempKey]`